# readability returning negative value

Tags: c, cs50

I have written code for cs50 readability using C. I keep receiving a negative value no matter what sentence I use to test. It is clearly a problem in my math however have used debugger and I can see that everything seems to be correct until the Coleman-Liau index is implemented. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I have added code bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h> //getstring
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main (void) 
    {
        string text = get_string ("Text:") ; //get input from user
        int letter = 0, word = 1, sentance = 0; 
        
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++) 
      
        if (isalpha(text[i]))      //identify how many characters are alphabetical
        {
            letter++;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++) 
        if (isspace(text[i]))     //identify how many spces there are 
        {
            word++;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
        if ((text[i]) == '!' || (text[i]) == '?' || (text[i]) == '.')
        {
            sentance++;
        }
        
    
         
        float l = (letter / word) *100.00; //average number of letters per 100 words
        float s = (word / sentance) * 100.00; //average number of words per sentance
        float index = 0.0588 * l - 0.296 * s - 15.8; 
        int round_index = round(index);
        
         if (round_index < 16 && round_index > 1)
        {
            printf("Grade %i \n", round_index);
        } 
        else if (round_index >= 16) 
        {
            printf("Grade 16+ \n") ;
        }
        else if (round_index < 1) 
        {
            printf("Before Grade 1 \n") ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `float`; use `double`.  `float` is a limited range/precision floating-point type mainly used for saving storage in large arrays.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` brings in a standard ISO C header which contains declarations of functions like `strlen` and `memcpy`. There is a `get_string` in the `<cs50.h>` header, not in `<string.h>`.

Comment: A `.` character doesn't necessarily end a sentence. It occurs in abbreviations like `i. d.` and `Mr.`.  If the text rigidly follows certain conventions, then you can count on a `.` that is followed by at least two spaces (or that occurs at the end of the data) to be a sentence-ender.

Comment: `n = strlen(text);` - Why are you doing this multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You might fall into the integer division trap: both `letter`, `word` and `sentance` are declared as `int`, so integer division is done.

Examples:

```
7 / 2 = 3
6 / 7 = 0 (when the second one is larger, you always get zero)
```

In order to avoid this, you might declare `letter` and/or `word` and/or `sentance` as floating point numbers. (You only need to have one floating point number in order to force floating point arithmetic, but best is to declare all of them as floating point numbers)

Just one remark: why do you still use `float` as floating point number? Mostly people are using `double` nowadays (don't ask me why).
Sorry, second remark: `sentance`, shouldn't that be `sentence` (with an "e")? :-)

Comment: Thank you so much :) I realised I was doing words/sentences instead of sentences/words which seems to have fixed the problem but thanks for tip.

Comment: You're welcome. In case my answer was useful or solved your problem, please upvote or accept it (this is how this site works).